# I need to make multiples of an object

Tags: file-format

I am making dominos and need to create each one with the right numbers on it is it best to create these in a separate file or can I make them on different layers to export to unreal.

Comment: This is mostly an opinion based question, it is really up to you to decide how you want to organize your scene, although for something so simple keeping separate files, scenes, or even layers seems overkill. Just line them side by side, minding your objects centers should suffice.

Comment: Also, you only have 20 layers...